# Find the absolute maxima and minima of a multivariable equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find the absolute maxima and minima of the function $g(x, y) = 3x^2 + 2y^2 − 4y$ in the region bounded by the curves $y = 4$ and $y = x^2$

I first took the first order partial derivatives:

$g_x=6x$

$g_y=4y-4$

I then set them equal to $0$ and solved for the values of $x$ and $y$

$6x=0$, $x=0$

$4y-4=0$, $y=1$

So my critical points are $x=0$ and $y=1$

Plugging these into my original equation gives $g(0,1) = -2$

From here, how do I obtain the absolute maxima and minima?

Comment: I believe you mean $g_x=6x$

Comment: @ASKASK yes thanks for catching that!

Comment: In general, use the [second partial derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test).

Comment: Put $y = 4$ and $y = x^2$ into $g(x,y)$ and check min and max for that function and compare the with what you have gotten.

Comment: @BenLongo that only finds **relative** maxima and minima

Comment: A global extrema is a also a local extrema.

Comment: @BenLongo you still have to check other possible critical points in the region. Your method doesn't help there.

Comment: @BenLongo Region is bounded by $y = 4$ and $y = x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to check if your function $g$ has any extrema on the boundary of the the given region. Your method doesn't find these extrema, as the function need not be flat on the boundary to be maximal or minimal there.

Consider the top of the region given by $y=4$, and plug $y=4$ into $g(x,y)$:

$$f(x) := g(x,4) =3x^2+2\cdot 4^2 - 4\cdot 4 = 3x^2+16.$$

Then $f'(x) = 6x$, so $f'(x) = 0\Leftrightarrow x=0$ meaning that your function $g(x,y)$ is maximal on the boundary $y=4$ at $(0,4)$.

Next plug $y=x^2$ into $g(x,y)$:

$$h(x) := g(x,x^2)$$

and do the same thing as above.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  So please help me to understand, do the critical points that I find just tell me that something is happening at those points (i.e. a maxima or a minima)?

Comment: I do understand now why we need to check the boundary points

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting as
$$g(x,y)=3x^2+2(y-1)^2-2$$
Minima happens obviously at (0,1) and the minimum value is -2.

Maxima happens at (a,b) where the an ellipse with the following equation
$$3x^2+2(y-1)^2=k^2$$
extends as much as possible within the region.
This happens at the crossing between two boundaries, i.e. $(a,b)=(\pm2,4)$.
$$k^2=3a^2+2(b-1)^2=30$$
So the maxima is
$$k^2-2=28$$